# function to change cell when the data is automatically updated

Tags: google-sheets

I have a script that sends an updated data every 5 minutes in cell E2, I would like this data to be automatically written to another cell every time it changes

Comment: What about inserting into the cell to which you want to copy the data the formula `=E2`?

Comment: it's an active cell with a value that changes every 5 minutes, I want not to overwrite the value

Comment: Do you want it to be written on every value change into a new cell?

Comment: Sorry ,i need the solution now

Comment: var sheet =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var range = sheet.getRange("E2:E2");
range.insertCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);

Comment: You did not answer my question, but if what you needs is to write the content of `E2` always to the same cell, you can do something like `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); sheet.getRange("F2").setValue(sheet.getRange("E2");` But if you want the script to run automatically on each update, you will need a workaround with `onChange` and `=IMPORTRANGE()`, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59362734/on-edit-doesnt-work-if-cell-auto-updates-need-a-workaround-google-sheets/59370962#59370962)

Comment: Hi sorry my english language, I found the solution, add a cell under E2 every update.Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 function dataFlow(){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 var data = ss.getRange("E2").getValue();
 // enter cell position where you want data to populate
 ss.getRange("").setValue(data);
 }
```

Comment: thanks shiva, can this new function be written in the same project did i have to create a new project?

Comment: you can add it to existing script without `function dataFlow(){` and also in last line you need to add the cell value in `ss.getRange("here")` where you want the result