# Incomplete run with installable triggers - script on gsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[SCRIPT Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6AlR.png)

I use google script in a gsheet to automatically duplicate some lines according to a given criteria. When I run manually the script, everything is done as I wish. I set an installable trigger to run the script every day. But it runs and does nothing (2 secs run vs 50 secs run in manual). After some research I found out it could be because of some authorization restrictions but I do not know how to fix it. An additional info is that I am not the owner of the gsheet, but I have the edit access. Can it be the reason ?

Comment: Code should be added as text not as image.

Answer (score 0):

### If you are using the onEdit trigger the reason for it not to work is that you perform automatic duplicates

- The `onEdit` trigger - be it simple or installable do not fire on non-human edits because of [restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions):

  > Script executions and API requests do not cause triggers to run.
- If you are interested in a (a bit convoluted) workaround - you can make a copy of your spreadsheet which you synchronize with the `=ImportRange` cell formula
- If you bind your script to the copy and change the trigger from `onEdit` to `onChange` - it will fire on the `Importrange` updates - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59362734/on-edit-doesnt-work-if-cell-auto-updates-need-a-workaround-google-sheets/59370962#59370962) for more information

## If you are using the time-driven trigger, the problem must be in the function itself

Most useful for debugging is implementing logs at strategic positions, especially inside loop and if statements

Comment: Actually it is a time-driven trigger. The execution of the script is trigered at the right time but the run is not complete, nothing is done even if no error is raised.

Comment: When you go to `View-Executions` - can you see any error there? Can you provide your code (the function that runs on trigger) for troubleshooting?

Comment: No error or log in the execution detail (link in the original question above). For the script picture, just to let you know : "linkUrl" returns the original url of an hyperlink and "firstEmptyRow" returns the number corresponding to the first empty row. ssid and ssName are normally replaced by the real name and id.

Comment: I cannot see anything in your code that should not execute on time-driven trigger if it does so correctly run from the editor. You just have to make sure that the CREATOR of the trigger has edit access to the spreadsheet in question. However, if this were not the case - you should see errors in the execution logs. If your trigger is called correctly and does not throw errors - maybe after all the error is in the code algorithms themselves? Afterall you have two nested loops. I recommend you to implement logs (e.g. `emptyRow`, `VIN-cell`) within the loop and study them after execution.

Comment: I used logs to investigate. I found out that I used the method .getActiveSheet() in my handmade methods "linkUrl" and "firstEmptyRow". It explains everything and now I put the sheet in parameter of these methods. It has ruled everything. Thank you for your help

Comment: I am glad you found the issue and updated my answer accordnigly.