# Google Sheets Cell Formatting Conditional on Cell Change (GOOGLEFINANCE)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, cell, blink

I am trying to achieve the following: I have a google sheet with a stock price pulled from =GOOGLEFINANCE("ticker", "price"). I want that cell containing the stock price to flash green or red conditional on that cell updating with a higher or lower price as before.

I want to avoid having any form of helper cells, storing old values of the price, etc.

Is this something a script would achieve?

Thanks a lot for your help, everyone!

Comment: Probably not because there is no trigger that responds to changes in data.

Comment: Yes, you can do it by script if you mirror your sheet with `=importrange` into a different sheet /spreadsheet and that use the onChange trigger - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59370962/11599789).

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use some params from googlefinance command, for example, you need a current value and an old value to compare, so get old values on googlefinance you use like that:

```
GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG","price",TODAY()-30,TODAY())
```

and to the current value:

```
GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG","price")
```

now you need add conditional rules

So you need to select the cell where you need to apply the condition, so click on '**format**' (bar menu) and click finally on '**conditional formatting**' and apply your rules on the side menu that will open.

Docs:

- [Google Finance Doc](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en-GB)
- [Google Conditional Doc](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cexample)