# e.changeType returning "EDIT" on new row addition. Expected value is "INSERT_ROW"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have processes to be fired only **when a new row is added** to google spreadsheets. According to the documentation, the changeType can have the following values:

The type of change (EDIT, INSERT_ROW, INSERT_COLUMN, REMOVE_ROW, REMOVE_COLUMN, INSERT_GRID, REMOVE_GRID, FORMAT, or OTHER).

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

Somehow, the event is always returning "EDIT" even when we add a new row or edit an existing row. As a result of this, I'm unable to differentiate between an edit on an existing row and new row addition.

Trigger details:

Choose which function to run: test

Which runs at deployment: head

Select event source: from spreadsheet

Select event type: on change

Test function:

```
function test(e) {
  var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (activeSheet.getName() == "Feedback"){
    Logger.log(e.changeType);
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you `add a new row`? Do you mean inserting a new row? Or copy-pasting vvalues into a new row?

Comment: @ziganotschka by inserting a new row: form submission through a web app

Comment: @tn2411 [Edit] your question to make it clear  that you're not manually inserting the row but a script is doing  that.

Comment: @TheMaster I'm not manually inserting a row. I have a web app running on glide apps which adds new row to the spreadsheet.

Comment: This is the reason your trigger is not working as intended - Apps Script triggers only fire on human edits and some formula-triggered updates. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59362734/on-edit-doesnt-work-if-cell-auto-updates-need-a-workaround-google-sheets/59370962#59370962) for a workaround.