# How to check if a sheet cells includes errors or not?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I am using this script function to check if my cell functions in sheet has any errors or not.

Here is the code but it does not seems to be working. It keeps on saying no error when i have an error in a cell

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourcename = "Sheet1";
  var source = ss.getSheetByName(sourcename);

  var cell = source.getRange("A1:AG30");

function isError2(cell) { 
  const errorValues = ["#NULL!", "#DIV/0!", "#VALUE!", "#REF!", "#NAME?", "#NUM!", "#N/A","#ERROR!"];
  if (errorValues.includes(cell) != true) {
  Logger.log("no error");
  } else{
    Logger.log("some error");
  }
  
}
```

---

```
function isError2() {  
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sourcename = "Sheet1";
      var source = ss.getSheetByName(sourcename);

      var cell = source.getRange("A1:AG30");
      const errorValues = ["#NULL!", "#DIV/0!", "#VALUE!", "#REF!", "#NAME?", "#NUM!", "#N/A","#ERROR!"];
      if (errorValues.includes(cell) != true) {
      Logger.log("no error");
      } else{
        Logger.log("some error");
      }

    }
```

---

Updated the approach but still having no luck with the desired output

```
var mysheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
 var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(mysheet);

function findErrors(sheet) {
   const errorValues = ["#NULL!", "#DIV/0!", "#VALUE!", "#REF!", "#NAME?", "#NUM!", "#N/A","#ERROR!"];
    
  var singleSheetArray = [];

  var name = sheet1.getName();
   
  // how many cells in the sheet currently
  var maxRows = sheet1.getMaxRows();
  var maxCols = sheet1.getMaxColumns();
  
  var totalCells = maxRows * maxCols;
  
  // how many cells have data in them
  var r = sheet1.getLastRow();
  var c = sheet1.getLastColumn();
  var data_counter = r * c;
  
  if (data_counter !== 0) {
  
    var dataRange = sheet1.getRange(1,1,r,c);
    var dataValues = dataRange.getValues();

    dataValues.forEach(function(row) {
      row.forEach(function(cell) {
        if ((errorValues.indexOf(cell) === -1) )  {
           SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("no errors in "+cell);          
          data_counter --;
        } 
          
      });
    });  
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Change alert to `alert("no errors in "+cell);` and show screenshot  when cell has a error, but it still shows no error.

Comment: It should show "no errors in #ERROR" or something like that to prove your claim that it it shows no errors in a errored cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**

> Unable to check whether the cell has an error

**Explanation**

The issue you are facing is a simple type mismatch. `getRange()` method returns an instance of `Range`, while you try to compare it to a member of a `errorValues` array, which consists of **strings**. Therefore, `errorValues.includes(cell)` will always be `false`, hence first block of the conditional statement executing.

**Solution**

Use `getValues()` on the range, it will return you a 2-dimensional array of values. If you are only interested in one row (which you probably are), extract it and loop over the cells with `some` (or `every`) method, doing the same comparison.

**Notes**

1. On using global variables in custom functions and in GAS in general. You *can* use them, GAS environment is a JavaScript runtime with a convenience layer that simplifies working with Google APIs, nearly everything that's valid in JS is valid here. That being said, *do treat global variables as if they don't exist* - unless you know exactly what you are doing.

**References**

1. `getRange` method [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column)
2. `getValues` method [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
3. Custom functions [guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#autocomplete)
4. `every` method [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) on MDN (see `some` there)

Comment: Hi @Oleg Valter thank you for all the explanation, definitely helps me in understanding the concept. One thing is that I am not interested in just one row or column. I have functions in the cell in multiple rows and columns which is why I used range.  That being said, I just tried getValues and still getting false as returned value. `var cell = source.getRange("A1:AG30").getValues();`

Comment: Yep, as you should - you just substituted `Range` instance for an instance of array :) Please, take a look at the `every` and `some` methods and what the structure of the output returned by `getValues()` is - every top-level member represents a row and each row is an array consisting of values - it is the latter that you want to compare against

Comment: Just to clarify, is that what you are referring to as I just tried this and still no luck?  `var cell = source.getRange(1,1,30,30).getValues();`

Comment: Correct, to that one - doing that is only step one - please see the second part of the answer and read  up on methods used for looping over arrays - if you want to check that *none* of the cells have issues, then use nested `every` method calls to achieve that.

Comment: Hi  @Oleg Valter as per your suggested, I tried looking into every but having a hard time in understanding how to adapt the approach in the function. I am trying the loop in a different way but i followed your suggestion. Just posted the updated code but still not able to get the desired result where i can simply trigger a simple alert if no error and if there are error, i would like to trigger an alert saying, there are errors. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Btw, `errorValues.indexOf(cell)  === -1` should be enough to check. Also, you could use `getDataRange()` -> `getValues()` to get all values without checking the area (?) of cells with data. Finally, recheck what `every` does - it returns a boolean, so you could nest the method calls. If the inner returns true, then all cells are without error. Then,  the same goes for the outer one, but it would check that the inner is true for all rows. After all loops done, use the result to decide whether to show the prompt or not - you are on the right track

Comment: Would it be possible for you to please help me with the code and how can i implement every in my updated code? Another issue I am having with the loop is that it is showing alert multiple time. I have to force the function to stop.

Answer (score 1):

Try to move the 4 variables inside your function. Apps script does not support global variables. So the function does not recognize the var cell.

EDIT: [Detect formula errors in Google Sheets using Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49161874/detect-formula-errors-in-google-sheets-using-script)

Comment: Hi @RemcoE33 then how my function should look like since cell is defined within function definition --> function isError2(cell)

Comment: Hi @RemcoE33 I have updated the function in the code and here, still no luck..same problem...it is always returning "false" value for --> errorValues.includes(cell)

Comment: Hi @RemcoE33 that's where I got the code from originally if you see my code is very similar but as I have mentioned it is not getting me the desired result. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hi @RemcoE33 - unfortunately, the statement that **Apps script does not support global variables** is simply not true and misleading. You can check by creating a custom function with global variables referenced correctly.

Comment: @RemcoE33 - that said, I must apologize and adjust my previous statement to just ask you to be more specific in the answer about what you mean by using global variables. I saw that the OP edited out the first version of the question [which is a bad practice] and as it stands now, it will make people think that you say that global vars as a well-defined term of variables defined in global scope are not supported